# Wpf datagrid with combobox,text and checkbox columns and saving into csv

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I had created a `wpf` datagrid with three columns.

```
Text column
Combobox Column
Checkbox column
```

The `Combobox` items are loaded in `C#` Code behind. I have done `binding` the `combobox` items using observable collection but the items are not getting displayed in `DG` after selection.

One more thing i need to save this `datagrid` as a `CSV`.

Comment: Usually when you have some problem with your not working code, it's better to post the code so we can really help you. If u just write what doesn't work we can just guess what could possibly be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on the property you have bound to the Combobox itemsource if you are setting (replacing) the entire ObservableCollection in your code behind.

Failing that also check your Output window for any binding errors e.g. typo's etc.

[This article](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/38-windows/1564-wpf-data-grid-to-csv-and-html-the-easy-way.html?start=1) describes saving datagrid data to csv